# DefaultCellStyle.Format not working after data entry in cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, number-formatting

I have two columns that I want formatted as "N2". However the one that is set to read only and on displays info works fine while the other column that allows data to be entered does not format the data after the user enters it.

```
 account_grid.Columns.Item(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
 account_grid.Columns.Item(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = vbShortDate
 account_grid.Columns.Item(8).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
```

Column 3 works fine and get populated with data when the grid is loaded. The data is formatted correctly (as N2).

Column 8 is empty to start and allows uses to enter data. After a users enters a number (for example 25678), I want the number format to change to 25,678. But it is not changing.

This is the code that populates the grid:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To account_list.Count - 1
   account_grid.Rows.Add(account_list(x)(0), account_list(x)(1), account_list(x)(2)...[to 8])
Next
```

Comment: Is the grid bound or unbound? That format specifier is only meaningful if the actual data is of a numeric type. If the data is `Strings` then there will be no formatting performed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by bound or unbound. It is not bound to a data adapter or anything. I simply create the grid and then fill it with data that I read from the database. The data is read from the database and then stored in an array. The array is used to populate the grid. The data for the column in question is in integer format from the database.

Comment: I think that you probably ought to show us the code that populates the grid.